# SQL Server: wrap a text column in quotes

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server:

```
select gender 
from people;
```

`gender` is a text column and values in it are

```
male, female, children
```

I want to achieve a output like 'male', 'female', 'children' and a blank when this column is NULL.

How do I achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`text` is not the right data type for `gender`. `text`, `ntext`, and `image` are all [**deprecated**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx) and incredible overkill for a column such as `gender`.

> IMPORTANT!  ntext, text, and image data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead.

using [**`coalesce()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx)

```
select coalesce(''''+convert(varchar(8),gender)+'''','') as gender from people;
```

or using [**`isnull()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx)

```
select isnull(''''+convert(varchar(8),gender)+'''','') as gender from people;
```

---

When quoting a single quote, you use two single quotes. e.g.

```
select '' as none, '''' as one, '''''' as two
```

returns:

```
+------+-----+-----+
| none | one | two |
+------+-----+-----+
|      | '   | ''  |
+------+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Thank you...When i tried it,sql server is giving a error - 'The data types varchar and text are incompatible in the add operator'...

Comment: @Oggu updated to convert to `varchar(8)`, but you really shouldn't need something that big. Also, `text` is not the right data type for `gender`. `text`, `ntext`, and `image` are all [**deprecated**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx) and incredible overkill for a column such as `gender`.

Comment: Thank you again !! it worked well..Also i will get the datatype changed to varchar(max) going fwd .